# Modals open but include _layout.cs

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am calling modal window from a page in my app. If the modal markup is included in the page the modal displays as I expect, but if I use a partial view the still modal opens but this time it contains the layout for the page defined in _Layout.cshmtl in addition to the content in the partial view.

```
<div id="itemDetailModal" class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="itemModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="itemModalLabel">
                    Item Name Here
                </h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <hr />
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4 col-md-4">
                        Item Number
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 col-md-8">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Item.Id, new { @class = "disabled" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function showDetails(itemId) {
        $(function() {
            debugger;

            var postbackUrl = "/Home/Details";
            var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: postbackUrl,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf8",
                data: { "id": itemId },
                datatype: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    debugger;
                    $('#requestModalContent').html(data);
                    $('#requestModal').modal(options);
                    $('#requestModal').modal('show');
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

When I use the same modal markup and javascript except for:

```
<div id="itemDetailModal" class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="itemModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div id="itemDetailModal"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The partial view is:

```
<div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="itemModalLabel">
                Item Name Here
            </h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <hr />
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 col-md-4">
                    Item Number
                </div>
                <div class="col-8 col-md-8">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Item.Id, new { @class = "disabled" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
        </div>
```

The modal content markup is in a partial view, but is identical to the markup in the first example.

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you mean you have a modal in partial view?Amd when you use it in another page,the page will contain the layout for the page defined in _Layout.cshml.Can you share the partial view and the page contains paritial view?

Comment: @YiyiYou yes, the markup for the modal is in a partial view. When the modal opens, it has the layout defined in _Layout.cshtml, the parent page also displays the layout. All the code relating to the modal, in partial view and parent page are displayed above. This project is .NET Framework 4.6

Comment: Hava you used like `@{layout="xxx/xxx/_layout.cshtml"}` in your partial view?

Comment: No, you can see all markup for the partial view displayed in the question.